# How to manage session in MVC Application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC but not known how to manage session.in my application for login I am using simple membership function.when i am first login to application works properly,but when logout is done and in address bar giving proper controller and action wihtout login it opens directly without login.I think at this situation session is required but how that apply is not known.
Please suggest some solution for this.

Advanced thank you.

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET MVC are you working on? Could you show the controller actions you're having issues with? We aren't able to help you unless you provide some information on what you've tried, or where it's going wrong.

Comment: i feel using of session for authentication is not a good way in live projects. Please use any other authentication methods. _Here are some good external links to do (also study) the same._ 1. [dotnet-tricks](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/G54G220114-Custom-Authentication-and-Authorization-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html) 2. [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET provides a framework for handling user authentication, called "Identity". This is available in both ASP.NET Core (latest) and ASP.NET 4, with good documentation available for both.

ASP.NET Core: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/identity.html

ASP.NET 4.6: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Both sites have examples of how to build up the applications with it.